# OleVariant stream to TStringList optimization

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-xe

My server returns a string stream as OleVariant via a COM/DCOM call.
This code works well for the client, but can probably be improved.
Hints are welcome.

And as a follow up, what if the server returns the OleVariant stream as UTF-8,
what is the best way for the client to convert it to unicode ?

```
procedure TClientToServer.GetText(       mode     : integer;
                                                 const infoText : widestring;
                                                      txt         : TStrings);
var
  size        : integer;
  dataP       : pointer;
  data        : OleVariant;
  strStream   : TStringStream;
begin
  txt.Clear;
  data:= fDComServer.GetData( mode,infoText);
  if VarIsNull(data) then Exit;
  size:= VarArrayHighBound(data,1) + 1;
  dataP:= VarArrayLock( data);
  try
    strStream:= TStringStream.Create;
    try
      strStream.Write( dataP^,size);
      strStream.Seek(0,0);
      txt.LoadFromStream( strStream);
    finally
      strStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    VarArrayUnlock( data);
  end;
end;
```

Edit :
  Going for UTF8 means that less bandwidth is used on the network, and I can reuse the COM/DCOM routines more or less intact when later implementing a http protocol interface based on UTF8 strings.

Thanks David for pointing me in the right direction to trim the code a little bit.

Here is the updated procedure :

```
procedure TClientToServer.GetText(       mode     : integer;
                                   const infoText : widestring;
                                         txt         : TStrings);
var
  size    : integer;
  dataP   : Pointer;
  data    : OleVariant;
  utf8Str : Utf8String;
begin
  txt.Clear;
  data:= fDComServer.GetData( mode,infoText);
  if VarIsNull(data) then Exit;
  size:= VarArrayHighBound(data,1) + 1;
  dataP:= VarArrayLock( data);
  try
    SetString( utf8Str, PAnsiChar(dataP), size);
    txt.Text:= utf8Str;
  finally
    VarArrayUnlock( data);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need the string stream. You can just call [`SetString()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.SetString) to create a Delphi string containing the contents of `dataP` and then assign that string to `txt.Text`. If you have UTF8 data then pass a UTF8 string to `SetString()`.

Using `SetString()` still involves an intermediate buffer allocation so I guess what would really be nice would be a read-only `TStream` descendant which you could pass a pointer and a size. You could that pass that stream to `TStrings.LoadFromStream`. It would be easy enough to write such a thing.

Do you actually have performance problems though? If not then why change from your current approach.

Comment: The streams can be up to 200 kBytes, so I'm troubled by the fact that I have to reallocate two times to get the result.

Comment: @LU RD 200kB is nothing really. Since you'll likely be doing something with this data afterwards then that will probably swamp the time you could save by removing one of the reallocs. But I'm guessing since only you know what you do with this text.

Comment: Performance will as you say not be a problem. I will try to implement your suggestions.

Comment: @LU Why change? I'm not sure you have a pressing need to.

Comment: David, see my updated question. The server and client now works fine using UTF8. Now I'm going to implement an additional http based client/server interface based on the same concept.